# Can I run another node server programmatically from current node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, child-process

I have to two different node process or server. One node server is just for update database and another node server is connected with web module.

Solution 1:
From my web node server I can run another node server as child process and I have done it successfully. But the main problem is when parent process is stop, child process will also stop.

Solution 2:
 
I can also easily connect with each other by using "json-socket" if two server is running.

But what I want is to run and stop another node server from running web node server using code when I need? Is it possible?

At Last I got the solution.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn(__dirname + '/someScript.sh', [], {
 detached: true ,
 stdio: [ 'ignore', 'ignore', 'ignore' ]
});

child.unref();
```

Now even we stop the parent process child process will continue.

Comment: So, you want to run and stop the db server from the web node server, and you also want the d server running even after the web node server has stopped, right?

Comment: Have you looked into something like pm2? You could also try using CLI from Node to start a non-child process and store the pid so you can close it or restart when you want. I'm sure there's a better solution than that though. Didn't want to post it as an answer because it's too sloppy...

Comment: @KostasX I just run another node server from my current node server.

Comment: Currently, this question is too broad for this site. It is not clear what your problem is, and you are presenting two solutions. It appears you are prompting answers which would ultimately be opinions about "which is best?", which is outside the scope of what we do here. If you can narrow this down to one problem you need help with (and not a range of solutions) then I'm sure there are many here who could help.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way would be to just execute bash scripts within your web node server. This way it is possible to define the child processes as independent and they won't stop if the node web server gets terminated.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec, child;

// to start the server
const startDBServer = exec('sh startDBServer.sh');
let dbServerPID = undefined;
startDBServer.stdout.on('data', (pid)=>{
    console.log(pid);
    // TODO format and get pid
    dbServerPID = pid;
});
startDBServer.stderr.on('data', (data)=>{
    console.error(data);
});

const stopDBServer = exec(`sh stopDBServer.sh ${dbServerPID}`);
```

the start bash script could be and would return the pid of the new process

```
/myDir/DBServer/npm start &
echo $!
```

the stop bash script could be

```
kill -9 $1
```

There are a lot of good [resources](https://stackfame.com/run-shell-script-file-or-command-nodejs) out there of how to execute bash commands on a node server.

Comment: I want to run another node server. Like: npm start another_server 
It should be from code.

Comment: You can execute npm start inside the start bash script or just exec npm start from the web node server, where is the problem?

Comment: I see. May be I understand now. I want to read the resource first. Thank you.